# Navigate using MenuItem onPress

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm using UI-Kitten's Topbar, and in there, I want to switch to a different Screen onPress:

```js
const MenuIcon = (props): IconElement => (
    <Icon
      {...props}
      name='three-bars'
    />
);

const InfoIcon = (props): IconElement => (
    <Icon
      {...props}
      name='info'
    />
);

export const TopNavigator = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = (): void => {
    setMenuVisible(!menuVisible);
  };

  const renderMenuAction = (): React.ReactElement => (
    <TopNavigationAction
      icon={MenuIcon}
      onPress={toggleMenu}
    />
  );
  const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
  const renderRightActions = (): React.ReactElement => (
    
    <>
      <OverflowMenu
        anchor={renderMenuAction}
        visible={menuVisible}
        onBackdropPress={toggleMenu}
      >
        <MenuItem 
          accessoryLeft={InfoIcon}
          title='About'
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('myScreenName')}
        />
      </OverflowMenu>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <Layout
      style={styles.container}
      level='1'
    >
      <TopNavigation
        alignment='center'
        title='App'
        accessoryRight={renderRightActions}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

When I now click the about, it says:

```
Property 'navigation' doesn't exist
```

I know that I have to do something with a navigation prop, but I don't really know where and how. I couldn't figure it out. Everything I've tried led to more errors and problems. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In the `TopNavigator` execution context, there is no definition of `navigation`. I don't know you comply with the hierarchy of `react-navigation`  rules or not. But if you did, you would call `useNavigation` hook in the `TopNavigator` function like the following:

```js
export const TopNavigator = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Then you shouldn't see that error.

Comment: I thought so too but then it said "Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?"

Comment: @umbreonben, Definitely, the `NavigationContainer` must be its parent, not a direct parent but must be.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What do I have to change

Comment: @umbreonben, In the React Tree the `TopNavigator` must be under the `NavigationContainer`. easy.

Comment: I dont have a NavigationContainer. Where do I have to put that?

Comment: @umbreonben, Please read the [docs of react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#wrapping-your-app-in-navigationcontainer), you must wrap all of your app by this provider component. without it, react-navigation hasn't got any meaning.

Comment: I don't use react-navigation though. Im using a component from UI Kitten @amerllica

Comment: @umbreonben, It seems you're so new to RN. the UI Kitten is just a UI framework for React Native, but the `react-navigation` is a library that provides navigating ability for your application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255157/discussion-between-umbreonben-and-amerllica).